# Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler play in class - Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclick

Im using an intent in a button to open the Activity but the app forces close. The error states about an resolve menu item onClick. I dont even know why it has happened. Im only new to android. A help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code for the button onclick

```
public class Terminal extends Fragment {

public Terminal(){}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_terminal, container, false);
    final Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Quiz

            Intent i = new Intent (getActivity(), Term.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Here is the Term class. Its too long btw.

```
private int mPendingPathBroadcasts = 0;
private BroadcastReceiver mPathReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String path = makePathFromBundle(getResultExtras(false));
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PATH_PREPEND_BROADCAST)) {
            mSettings.setPrependPath(path);
        } else {
            mSettings.setAppendPath(path);
        }
        mPendingPathBroadcasts--;

        if (mPendingPathBroadcasts <= 0 && mTermService != null) {
            populateViewFlipper();
            populateWindowList();
        }
    }
};
private static final int FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES = 0x20;

private TermService mTermService;
private ServiceConnection mTSConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        Log.i(TermDebug.LOG_TAG, "Bound to TermService");
        TermService.TSBinder binder = (TermService.TSBinder) service;
        mTermService = binder.getService();
        if (mPendingPathBroadcasts <= 0) {
            populateViewFlipper();
            populateWindowList();
        }
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mTermService = null;
    }
};

private ActionBarCompat mActionBar;
private int mActionBarMode = TermSettings.ACTION_BAR_MODE_NONE;

private WindowListAdapter mWinListAdapter;
private class WindowListActionBarAdapter extends WindowListAdapter implements UpdateCallback {
    private static final int TextAppearance_Holo_Widget_ActionBar_Title = 0x01030112;

    public WindowListActionBarAdapter(SessionList sessions) {
        super(sessions);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView label = new TextView(Term.this);
        String title = getSessionTitle(position, getString(R.string.window_title, position + 1));
        label.setText(title);
        if (AndroidCompat.SDK >= 13) {
            label.setTextAppearance(Term.this, TextAppearance_Holo_Widget_ActionBar_Title);
        } else {
            label.setTextAppearance(Term.this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
        }
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public void onUpdate() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(mViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild());
    }
}

private ActionBarCompat.OnNavigationListener mWinListItemSelected = new ActionBarCompat.OnNavigationListener() {
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
        int oldPosition = mViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild();
        if (position != oldPosition) {
            mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(position);
            if (mActionBarMode == TermSettings.ACTION_BAR_MODE_HIDES) {
                mActionBar.hide();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};

private boolean mHaveFullHwKeyboard = false;

private class EmulatorViewGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private EmulatorView view;

    public EmulatorViewGestureListener(EmulatorView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        if (view.isMouseTrackingActive()) return false;

        String link = view.getURLat(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if(link != null)
            execURL(link);
        else
            doUIToggle((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY(), view.getVisibleWidth(), view.getVisibleHeight());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        float absVelocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
        float absVelocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
        if (absVelocityX > Math.max(1000.0f, 2.0 * absVelocityY)) {
            if (velocityX > 0) {
                mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
            } else {
                mViewFlipper.showNext();
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

private boolean mUseKeyboardShortcuts;

private View.OnKeyListener mKeyListener = new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return backkeyInterceptor(keyCode, event) || keyboardShortcuts(keyCode, event);
    }

    /**
     * Keyboard shortcuts (tab management, paste)
     */
    private boolean keyboardShortcuts(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!mUseKeyboardShortcuts) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean isCtrlPressed = (event.getMetaState() & KeycodeConstants.META_CTRL_ON) != 0;
        boolean isShiftPressed = (event.getMetaState() & KeycodeConstants.META_SHIFT_ON) != 0;

        if (keyCode == KeycodeConstants.KEYCODE_TAB && isCtrlPressed) {
            if (isShiftPressed) {
                mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
            } else {
                mViewFlipper.showNext();
            }

            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeycodeConstants.KEYCODE_N && isCtrlPressed && isShiftPressed) {
            doCreateNewWindow();

            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeycodeConstants.KEYCODE_V && isCtrlPressed && isShiftPressed) {


            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make sure the back button always leaves the application.
     */
    private boolean backkeyInterceptor(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && mActionBarMode == TermSettings.ACTION_BAR_MODE_HIDES && mActionBar.isShowing()) {
            /* We need to intercept the key event before the view sees it,
               otherwise the view will handle it before we get it */
            onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    Log.e(TermDebug.LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mSettings = new TermSettings(getResources(), mPrefs);

    Intent broadcast = new Intent(ACTION_PATH_BROADCAST);
    if (AndroidCompat.SDK >= 12) {
        broadcast.addFlags(FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    }
    mPendingPathBroadcasts++;
    sendOrderedBroadcast(broadcast, PERMISSION_PATH_BROADCAST, mPathReceiver, null, RESULT_OK, null, null);

    broadcast = new Intent(broadcast);
    broadcast.setAction(ACTION_PATH_PREPEND_BROADCAST);
    mPendingPathBroadcasts++;
    sendOrderedBroadcast(broadcast, PERMISSION_PATH_PREPEND_BROADCAST, mPathReceiver, null, RESULT_OK, null, null);

    TSIntent = new Intent(this, TermService.class);
    startService(TSIntent);

    if (!bindService(TSIntent, mTSConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE)) {
        Log.w(TermDebug.LOG_TAG, "bind to service failed!");
    }

    if (AndroidCompat.SDK >= 11) {
        int actionBarMode = mSettings.actionBarMode();
        mActionBarMode = actionBarMode;
        switch (actionBarMode) {
        case TermSettings.ACTION_BAR_MODE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE:
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_Holo);
            break;
        case TermSettings.ACTION_BAR_MODE_HIDES:
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_Holo_ActionBarOverlay);
            break;
        }
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.term_activity);
    mViewFlipper = (TermViewFlipper) findViewById(VIEW_FLIPPER);

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TermDebug.LOG_TAG);
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int wifiLockMode = WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL;
    if (AndroidCompat.SDK >= 12) {
        wifiLockMode = WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF;
    }
    mWifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(wifiLockMode, TermDebug.LOG_TAG);

    ActionBarCompat actionBar = ActivityCompat.getActionBar(this);
    if (actionBar != null) {
        mActionBar = actionBar;
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBarCompat.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBarCompat.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
        if (mActionBarMode == TermSettings.ACTION_BAR_MODE_HIDES) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
    }

    mHaveFullHwKeyboard = checkHaveFullHwKeyboard(getResources().getConfiguration());

    updatePrefs();
    mAlreadyStarted = true;
}

private String makePathFromBundle(Bundle extras) {
    if (extras == null || extras.size() == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    String[] keys = new String[extras.size()];
    keys = extras.keySet().toArray(keys);
    Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
    Arrays.sort(keys, collator);

    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();
    for (String key : keys) {
        String dir = extras.getString(key);
        if (dir != null && !dir.equals("")) {
            path.append(dir);
            path.append(":");
        }
    }

    return path.substring(0, path.length()-1);
}

private void populateViewFlipper() {
    if (mTermService != null) {
        mTermSessions = mTermService.getSessions();
        mTermSessions.addCallback(this);

        if (mTermSessions.size() == 0) {
            mTermSessions.add(createTermSession());
        }

        for (TermSession session : mTermSessions) {
            EmulatorView view = createEmulatorView(session);
            mViewFlipper.addView(view);
        }

        updatePrefs();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int flags = intent.getFlags();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if ((flags & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) == 0 &&
                action != null) {
            if (action.equals(RemoteInterface.PRIVACT_OPEN_NEW_WINDOW)) {
                mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(mTermSessions.size()-1);
            } else if (action.equals(RemoteInterface.PRIVACT_SWITCH_WINDOW)) {
                int target = intent.getIntExtra(RemoteInterface.PRIVEXTRA_TARGET_WINDOW, -1);
                if (target >= 0) {
                    mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(target);
                }
            }
        }

        mViewFlipper.resumeCurrentView();
    }
}

private void populateWindowList() {
    if (mActionBar == null) {
        // Not needed
        return;
    }

    if (mTermSessions != null) {
        int position = mViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild();
        WindowListAdapter adapter = mWinListAdapter;
        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new WindowListActionBarAdapter(mTermSessions);
            mWinListAdapter = adapter;

            SessionList sessions = mTermSessions;
            sessions.addCallback(adapter);
            sessions.addTitleChangedListener(adapter);
            mViewFlipper.addCallback(adapter);
            mActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, mWinListItemSelected);
        } else {
            adapter.setSessions(mTermSessions);
        }
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mViewFlipper.removeAllViews();
    unbindService(mTSConnection);
    if (mStopServiceOnFinish) {
        stopService(TSIntent);
    }
    mTermService = null;
    mTSConnection = null;
    if (mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
        mWakeLock.release();
    }
    if (mWifiLock.isHeld()) {
        mWifiLock.release();
    }
}

private void restart() {
    startActivity(getIntent());
    finish();
}

protected static TermSession createTermSession(Context context, TermSettings settings, String initialCommand) {
    ShellTermSession session = new ShellTermSession(settings, initialCommand);
    session.setProcessExitMessage(context.getString(R.string.process_exit_message));

    return session;
}

private TermSession createTermSession() {
    TermSettings settings = mSettings;
    TermSession session = createTermSession(this, settings, settings.getInitialCommand());
    session.setFinishCallback(mTermService);
    return session;
}

private TermView createEmulatorView(TermSession session) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    TermView emulatorView = new TermView(this, session, metrics);

    emulatorView.setExtGestureListener(new EmulatorViewGestureListener(emulatorView));
    emulatorView.setOnKeyListener(mKeyListener);
    registerForContextMenu(emulatorView);

    return emulatorView;
}



private EmulatorView getCurrentEmulatorView() {
    return (EmulatorView) mViewFlipper.getCurrentView();
}

private void updatePrefs() {
    mUseKeyboardShortcuts = mSettings.getUseKeyboardShortcutsFlag();

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    mViewFlipper.updatePrefs(mSettings);

    for (View v : mViewFlipper) {
        ((EmulatorView) v).setDensity(metrics);
        ((TermView) v).updatePrefs(mSettings);
    }

    if (mTermSessions != null) {
        for (TermSession session : mTermSessions) {
            ((ShellTermSession) session).updatePrefs(mSettings);
        }
    }

    {
        Window win = getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = win.getAttributes();
        final int FULLSCREEN = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        int desiredFlag = mSettings.showStatusBar() ? 0 : FULLSCREEN;
        if (desiredFlag != (params.flags & FULLSCREEN) || (AndroidCompat.SDK >= 11 && mActionBarMode != mSettings.actionBarMode())) {
            if (mAlreadyStarted) {
                restart();
            } else {
                win.setFlags(desiredFlag, FULLSCREEN);
                if (mActionBarMode == TermSettings.ACTION_BAR_MODE_HIDES) {
                    mActionBar.hide();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int orientation = mSettings.getScreenOrientation();
    int o = 0;
    if (orientation == 0) {
        o = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED;
    } else if (orientation == 1) {
        o = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    } else if (orientation == 2) {
        o = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    } else {
    }
    setRequestedOrientation(o);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SessionList sessions = mTermSessions;
    TermViewFlipper viewFlipper = mViewFlipper;
    if (sessions != null) {
        sessions.addCallback(this);
        WindowListAdapter adapter = mWinListAdapter;
        if (adapter != null) {
            sessions.addCallback(adapter);
            sessions.addTitleChangedListener(adapter);
            viewFlipper.addCallback(adapter);
        }
    }
    if (sessions != null && sessions.size() < viewFlipper.getChildCount()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < viewFlipper.getChildCount(); ++i) {
            EmulatorView v = (EmulatorView) viewFlipper.getChildAt(i);
            if (!sessions.contains(v.getTermSession())) {
                v.onPause();
                viewFlipper.removeView(v);
                --i;
            }
        }
    }

    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    String defValue = getDir("HOME", MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath();
    String homePath = mPrefs.getString("home_path", defValue);
    editor.putString("home_path", homePath);
    editor.commit();

    mSettings.readPrefs(mPrefs);
    updatePrefs();

    if (onResumeSelectWindow >= 0) {
        viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(onResumeSelectWindow);
        onResumeSelectWindow = -1;
    }
    viewFlipper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SessionList sessions = mTermSessions;
    TermViewFlipper viewFlipper = mViewFlipper;

    viewFlipper.onPause();
    if (sessions != null) {
        sessions.removeCallback(this);
        WindowListAdapter adapter = mWinListAdapter;
        if (adapter != null) {
            sessions.removeCallback(adapter);
            sessions.removeTitleChangedListener(adapter);
            viewFlipper.removeCallback(adapter);
        }
    }

    if (AndroidCompat.SDK < 5) {
        mBackKeyPressed = false;
    }


    final IBinder token = viewFlipper.getWindowToken();
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(token, 0);
        }
    }.start();
}

private boolean checkHaveFullHwKeyboard(Configuration c) {
    return (c.keyboard == Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY) &&
        (c.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    mHaveFullHwKeyboard = checkHaveFullHwKeyboard(newConfig);

    EmulatorView v = (EmulatorView) mViewFlipper.getCurrentView();
    if (v != null) {
        v.updateSize(false);
    }

    if (mWinListAdapter != null) {
         mWinListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menu.findItem(R.id.menu_new_window), MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menu_new_window) {
        doCreateNewWindow();
    }
    if (mActionBarMode == TermSettings.ACTION_BAR_MODE_HIDES) {
        mActionBar.hide();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void doCreateNewWindow() {
    if (mTermSessions == null) {
        Log.w(TermDebug.LOG_TAG, "Couldn't create new window because mTermSessions == null");
        return;
    }

    TermSession session = createTermSession();
    mTermSessions.add(session);

    TermView view = createEmulatorView(session);
    view.updatePrefs(mSettings);

    mViewFlipper.addView(view);
    mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(mViewFlipper.getChildCount()-1);
}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent data) {
    switch (request) {
    case REQUEST_CHOOSE_WINDOW:
        if (result == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            int position = data.getIntExtra(EXTRA_WINDOW_ID, -2);
            if (position >= 0) {
                                    onResumeSelectWindow = position;
            } else if (position == -1) {
                doCreateNewWindow();
                onResumeSelectWindow = mTermSessions.size() - 1;
            }
        } else {
            if (mTermSessions == null || mTermSessions.size() == 0) {
                mStopServiceOnFinish = true;
                finish();
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) != 0) {
        return;
    }

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (action.equals(RemoteInterface.PRIVACT_OPEN_NEW_WINDOW)) {
        // New session was created, add an EmulatorView to match
        SessionList sessions = mTermSessions;
        if (sessions == null) {
            // Presumably populateViewFlipper() will do this later ...
            return;
        }
        int position = sessions.size() - 1;

        TermSession session = sessions.get(position);
        EmulatorView view = createEmulatorView(session);

        mViewFlipper.addView(view);
        onResumeSelectWindow = position;
    } else if (action.equals(RemoteInterface.PRIVACT_SWITCH_WINDOW)) {
        int target = intent.getIntExtra(RemoteInterface.PRIVEXTRA_TARGET_WINDOW, -1);
        if (target >= 0) {
            onResumeSelectWindow = target;
        }
    }
}




private void doToggleSoftKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);

}



private void doToggleActionBar() {
    ActionBarCompat bar = mActionBar;
    if (bar == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (bar.isShowing()) {
        bar.hide();
    } else {
        bar.show();
    }
}

private void doUIToggle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    switch (mActionBarMode) {
    case TermSettings.ACTION_BAR_MODE_NONE:
        if (AndroidCompat.SDK >= 11 && (mHaveFullHwKeyboard || y < height / 2)) {
            openOptionsMenu();
            return;
        } else {
            doToggleSoftKeyboard();
        }
        break;
    case TermSettings.ACTION_BAR_MODE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE:
        if (!mHaveFullHwKeyboard) {
            doToggleSoftKeyboard();
        }
        break;
    case TermSettings.ACTION_BAR_MODE_HIDES:
        if (mHaveFullHwKeyboard || y < height / 2) {
            doToggleActionBar();
            return;
        } else {
            doToggleSoftKeyboard();
        }
        break;
    }
    getCurrentEmulatorView().requestFocus();
}
private void execURL(String link)
{
    Uri webLink = Uri.parse(link);
    Intent openLink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webLink);
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> handlers = pm.queryIntentActivities(openLink, 0);
    if(handlers.size() > 0)
        startActivity(openLink);
}
}
```

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

your button is missing an onClick field.

```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"  <!-- Add this line of code with correct onClick method -->
    android:text="Button" />
```

```

Checkout the [android pages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) for more info on this. Also checkout the [udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853) course for android development as well as the [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/androidpart1) course. They are both great for learning the basics of android development. I've done the udacity course and it's not too bad. I have also heard good things about the coursera course. Good Luck!

---